# Object vs adverbial

Tags: syntactic-analysis, objects, direct-objects, indirect-objects

In the sentence:

> "*The teachers in our school are nice*."

Is "in our school" an adverbial or part of the subject "The teachers in our school"?

Wondering because it would apply then to stuff like

> *"The man from Spain is  funny."*

With "from Spain" as an adverbial.

Furthermore:

> *"We fed the boys chicken."*

Is "the boys" the IO and "chicken DO?

Thanks :))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112177/discussion-on-question-by-google-user-object-vs-adverbial).